# Why does every process need its own page table?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

I was reading about memory management techniques and was wondering:

**Why** does every process need its own page table?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does every process need its own page table?

It doesn't.  But every *address space* needs its own page table, and in most operating systems each process has its own address space.

(The OS for IBM iSeries has only a single page table, since it uses a "single address space" model.)

Comment: And in many OSes an address space belongs to a single process. Scheduled "process-like" tasks belonging the the same "process" (i.e. to the same address space) are called "threads".

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch -- Right.  Generally the major distinguishing characteristic of a "process" is that it has its own address space.  A task with its own address space is a "process", while a task which shares an address space is a "thread".  (And a "task" is the entity that is able to execute instructions.)  (But terminology varies considerably between operating systems -- these terms are not cast in concrete.)